ApplePay how to access requiredShippingContactFields
I have an apple pay button my site and the applePayConfig looks like this:
{
    targetDiv: 'applePayContainer',
    displayName: 'Apple Pay Payment',
    paymentRequest: {
        total: {
            label: 'Payment',
            amount: 10,
            type: 'final'
        },
        requiredShippingContactFields: ['name', 'phone', 'email'],
        countryCode: 'US',
        currencyCode: 'USD'
    }
}

That said, I require email but it never seems to get sent back to me even though I require it. Question is, how can I access the email before finishing the payment process?
I am using usaepay.
This documention has not been helpful but is relevant: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple_pay_on_the_web/applepaypaymentrequest/2216121-requiredshippingcontactfields
